# How to get Select Option Value in Views Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

This is my HTML form template

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="d-flex form-inputs">
<select class="form-select" aria-label=".form-select-lg" name="lang_txt">
<option value="span_to_eng">Spanish To English</option>
<option value="eng_to_span">English To Spanish</option>
<option value="french_to_eng">French To English</option>
</select>
<input name="txt" class="form-control p-3" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
<a href="#"><img src="/static/assets/image/search.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
</form>
```

I want to get User selected value from Select Option to views.

This is views function

```
def lang_convert_view(request):
if request.method == "POST" and 'txt' in request.POST:
    txt = request.POST.get('txt')
    selected_lang = request.POST['lang_txt']
    data = custom_function_name(txt)
    context = {'data': data}
else:
    context = {}
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Anyone, please help me

Comment: Give values to your option tag and name attribute to select tag and then get that name in your views eg. *(`request.POST['my_select_tag_name']`)* you'll get selected value

Comment: Hi @AnkitTiwari, I have made some changes my code. Did you mean it?

Comment: Hello @Raj Yes, your edit is correct & one suggesion will be if it's not required then remove this line `and 'txt' in request.POST` inside your if

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution

```
request.POST.get('lang_txt')
```

lang_txt is the name of select tag

Comment: Also, better `request.POST.get('lang_txt')`.